# Break-point is not hitting webapi's delete operation

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

WebApi's delete operation is not working and as a response, below information is being returned which does not give any clue whats going wrong. Why the delete operation is not hitting execution path.

```html
 [HttpDelete]
        public void Delete([FromUri]string id)
        {
                using (var context = new EmployeeEntities())
                {
                   // Deletion logic
                }

        }
```

Comment: Please post a RELEVANT error message not the beginning of the HTML error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below in your Web.Config and check the response,

```
<system.webServer>
          <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          </modules>
    </system.webServer>
```